# Script all SQL database objects into VS Database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, scripting

I'm trying to put my database scripts into a VS Database project (I haven't generated them yet).

I'm assuming there should be some kind of "auto generate all" functionality, but I can't find anything.

Or do I really have to generate them one by one manually from management studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out if you open server explorer you can just drag and drop the objects into the database project. :)

Answer (score 0):

In VS, Data->Schema Compare.  Source = your database.  Destination = Your Project.