# Reload database objects in a VS database project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

if I create a `SQL Server 2008 Database Project` in Visual Studio 2010, then I am able to right click the project and select `Import Database Objects and Settings...`. I can do that **exactly one time** (even if I get an error while importing). If I did it one time, the option is grayed-out.

But after I have imported my objects, I couldn't find a way to reload or refresh the objects. A good example would be, that I have a database project of a whole database and someone adds something to the database directly. Now I want to have new table (function, procedure, etc.) in my project, too.

There has to be a better way than copy&paste to add new existing database objects to my database project?

I found this question:
[Script all SQL database objects into VS Database project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765948/script-all-sql-database-objects-into-vs-database-project)

But I neither have a Schema Compare option, nor can I drag&drop files from the server explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio you should see a menu choice that says Data. If you click on that, you should be able to run a Schema Compare. If you're not seeing that, then there's something wrong with your VS install or the project or maybe both.

Comment: Guess I found the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx - Nice if the company only gives you a Professional version of Visual Studio. Schema Compare needs Premium or Ultimate. So that's wrong with my Visual Studio.

Comment: Ouch! I wasn't aware of that one. When Project Juneau comes out I think it works on Standard too, but I could be wrong about that.